# GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame invoked delay

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

Pseudo codes like this:

```
situation0:
long start,end;
long frameInterval,invokeInterval,executeTime;
//GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame
onDrawFrame(){
    long cur = System.nanoTime();
    frameInterval = cur - start;
    invokeInterval = cur - end;
    start = cur;

    //some logic codes
    logicUpdate();
    //commit gl commands
    renderUpdate();

    end = System.nanoTime();
    executeTime = end-start;
}

situation1:
long start,end;
long frameInterval,invokeInterval,executeTime;
//logicThread
run(){
    while(true)
    {
        logicUpdate();
    }
}
//GLSurfaceView.Renderer.onDrawFrame
onDrawFrame(){
    long cur = System.nanoTime();
    frameInterval = cur - start;
    invokeInterval = cur - end;
    start = cur;
    
    renderUpdate();

    end = System.nanoTime();
    executeTime = end-start;
}
```

In situation0 : frameInterval = 40 ms,invokeInterval = 7 ms,executeTime = 33 ms
In situation1 : frameInterval = 41 ms,invokeInterval = 31 ms,executeTime = 10 ms

Geometries in the scene are same between S0 and S1, why GPU render cost (invokeInterval, I think) differently?

Comment: And I capture the scene by RenderDoc, the render command lists are rarely different too